# Mysql query to sort records in sequence for every iteration?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

i have table structure as follows.. `Number` , `Seq` and `Code` i want to make `Seq` in the order like sequence 1.2.3..4 for every `Number` is same,this sequence change for every change in `Number`.. the next `Seq` start from 1.2...to max..like in desired output.. How to do that? any help will be appreciated..Thanks in advance..

```
CREATE TABLE `unsorted` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Number` int(5) default NULL,
  `Seq` int(3) default NULL,
  `Code` varchar(6) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `unsorted`
--

INSERT INTO `unsorted` (`id`, `Number`, `Seq`, `Code`) VALUES
(1, 107, 3, 'KRMI'),
(2, 107, 4, 'MAO'),
(3, 107, 1, 'SWV'),
(4, 107, 2, 'THVM'),
(5, 108, 2, 'KRMI'),
(6, 108, 1, 'MAO'),
(7, 108, 4, 'SWV'),
(8, 108, 3, 'THVM'),
(9, 401, 1, 'AWB'),
(10, 401, 9, 'AY'),
(11, 401, 8, 'BBK'),
(12, 401, 12, 'BSB'),
(13, 401, 3, 'BSL'),
(14, 401, 6, 'CNB'),
(15, 401, 5, 'JHS'),
(16, 401, 11, 'JNU'),
(17, 401, 4, 'KNW'),
(18, 401, 7, 'LKO'),
(19, 401, 2, 'MMR'),
(20, 401, 10, 'SHG'),
(21, 421, 4, 'BE'),
(22, 421, 2, 'FGR'),
(23, 421, 3, 'KSJ'),
(24, 421, 1, 'LKO'),
(25, 421, 5, 'SVDK'),
(26, 422, 2, 'BE'),
(27, 422, 4, 'FGR'),
(28, 422, 3, 'KSJ'),
(29, 422, 5, 'LKO'),
(30, 422, 1, 'SVDK');
```

Desired Output:

```
CREATE TABLE `sorted` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Number` int(5) default NULL,
  `Seq` int(3) default NULL,
  `Code` varchar(6) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sorted`
--

INSERT INTO `sorted` (`id`, `Number`, `Seq`, `Code`) VALUES
(1, 107, 1, 'SWV'),
(2, 107, 2, 'THVM'),
(3, 107, 3, 'KRMI'),
(4, 107, 4, 'MAO'),
(5, 108, 1, 'MAO'),
(6, 108, 2, 'KRMI'),
(7, 108, 3, 'THVM'),
(8, 108, 4, 'SWV'),
(9, 401, 1, 'AWB'),
(10, 401, 2, 'MMR'),
(11, 401, 3, 'BSL'),
(12, 401, 4, 'KNW'),
(13, 401, 5, 'JHS'),
(14, 401, 6, 'CNB'),
(15, 401, 7, 'LKO'),
(16, 401, 8, 'BBK'),
(17, 401, 9, 'AY'),
(18, 401, 10, 'SHG'),
(19, 401, 11, 'JNU'),
(20, 401, 12, 'BSB'),
(21, 421, 1, 'LKO'),
(22, 421, 2, 'FGR'),
(23, 421, 3, 'KSJ'),
(24, 421, 4, 'BE'),
(25, 421, 5, 'SVDK'),
(26, 422, 1, 'SVDK'),
(27, 422, 2, 'BE'),
(28, 422, 3, 'KSJ'),
(29, 422, 4, 'FGR'),
(30, 422, 5, 'LKO');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a query something like :

```
SELECT * From table Order by Number, Seq Asc
```